# What is the difference between the following statements in terms of HashMap?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

While trying to declare the HashMap normally the code is written as

```
 Map<K,V> m = new HashMap<>();
```

If I try to create a hash map by the below mentioned code :

```
 HashMap<K,V> m = new HashMap<>();
```

What is the difference between the two declarations and which one should be preferred ?

Comment: *"...and which one should be preferred ?"* The first, unless you need something `HashMap` provides that `Map` doesn't. See the linked question's answers for details.